# How can I optimize these SQL joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

**TL;DR**

Here is the query with the joins I'd like to optimize.

```sql
SELECT D.Data1, D.Data2
FROM @DATA D
    INNER JOIN @FILTER F
        ON (
               (COALESCE(F.Filter1, D.Data1) = D.Data1)
               OR
               (
                   F.Filter1 < 0
                   AND F.Filter1 <> -D.Data1
               )
           )
           AND
           (
               (COALESCE(F.Filter2, D.Data2) = D.Data2)
               OR
               (
                   F.Filter2 < 0
                   AND F.Filter2 <> -D.Data2
               )
           );
```

**BACKGROUND**

Here's the scenario:

I have the following tables:

```sql
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (
    Data1 INT NOT NULL,
    Data2 INT NOT NULL,
--  ...
    DataN INT NOT NULL
);
DECLARE @FILTER TABLE (
    Filter1 INT NULL,
    Filter2 INT NULL,
--  ...
    FilterN INT NULL
)
```

The rows in `@DATA` need to be filtered column-wise by the rows in `@FILTER` according to the following rules:

> Let 1 < X < N.
>
> Assume `FilterX IS NULL OR FilterX > 0` is true for all X.
>
> Assume `DataX > 0` is true for all X.
>
> - If `FilterX is NULL` is true then `DataX` passes the filter.
> - If `FilterX > 0 AND FilterX = DataX` is true then `DataX` passes the filter.
> - If `FilterX < 0 AND FilterX != -DataX` is true then `DataX` passes the filter.
> - `DataX` fails the filter otherwise.
> - If `DataX` passes the filter for all `X` then return the `DATA` row.

Here is a two-column scenario:

```
COLUMNS:  Column1   Column2

DATA:     24        12
          23        12
          23        13 

FILTER:   24        NULL
          NULL      -12   

EXPECTED: 24        12
          23        13
```

The above example could be interpreted as

> Return all the rows of `DATA` where `Data1 = 24 OR Data2 <> -12`

My query above accomplishes the result, but in the business case I have about 16 fields instead of two, which makes for one ugly awful query. I'm wondering if there's a more performant way I can do these joins to accomplish the same result.

Comment: For performance i'd definitely be using temporary tables, not table variables. Also, what are you trying to achieve with this: `COALESCE(F.Filter1, D.Data1) = D.Data1)` if F.Filter1 is null then you're joining the D table to itself

Comment: The actual tables I'm using are material, I just used temporary tables here to model the problem.

The `COALESCE(F.Filter1, D.Data1) = D.Data1` is for when `F.Filter1` has a value I want to compare it with `D.Data1`, passing the join when they are equal, but if `F.Filter1` is `NULL` then `D.Data1` should pass, so I just join the value on itself.

Comment: ok great, and does the COALESCE above equate to the same logic as this? `(F.Filter1 = D.Data1 OR F.Filter1 IS NULL)`

Comment: Yes, the `COALESCE` should be equivalent to your alternative statement. However, in the business case since `F.Filter1` will be `NULL` more often than not, would swapping the statement into `F.Filter1 IS NULL OR F.Filter1 = D.Data1` be more performant?

EDIT: Actually they are not equivalent... when SQL executed it.. hold on..

EDIT: Nvrmnd, they are equivalent :)

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one filter on the same column (both positive and negative)?

Comment: Thanks Ruud, but I'm not sure I understand. Data1 will only ever be filtered by Filter1, for example, not Filter2 or any other filter. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that you appear to be suffering from is doing calculation in the `WHERE` clause. You can avoid some of it by doing something like this which I *think* matches your logic.

```
    FROM @DATA D
    INNER JOIN @FILTER F
    ON 
    (
        (F.Filter1 = D.Data1 OR F.Filter1 IS NULL)
        OR
        (
            F.Filter1 < 0
            AND F.Filter1 <> -D.Data1
        )
    )
    AND
    (
        (F.Filter2 = D.Data2 OR F.Filter2 IS NULL)
        OR
        (
            F.Filter2 < 0
            AND F.Filter2 <> -D.Data2
        )
    );
```

The main thing I'd be looking at after this is whether you have the correct indexes on your tables but we don't have access to your actual schema to check what indexes are in place.

Comment: I don't have a `WHERE` clause in my query.

Also, I'm functionally the DBA here so I can put whatever indexes I need to, if you have suggestions.

Comment: my apologies, the same logic stands for your joins